# "ffmpeg: command not found" - But it's in the current directory?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert some .png files I have into a movie using ffmpeg. I'm using the tutorial:

http://www.miscdebris.net/blog/2008/04/28/create-a-movie-file-from-single-image-files-png-jpegs/

The files have names Image001.png, Image002.png, ..., Image500.png, and Image501.png. I manually installed ffmpeg this morning from their website, so I don't have to do step 1. I then proceed to run:

```
cd Downloads
cd python-meep
cd Images
```

Where both my images and my folder containing the manually downloaded ffmpeg are located. Next, I type:

```
ffmpeg -qscale 5 -r 20 -b 9600 -i Image%03d.png movie.mp4
```

To my surprise, this is the error message I get:

```
ffmpeg: command not found
```

What's going on here? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. Could be relevant that I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Use `./ffmpeg -i Image%03d.png -c:v mpeg4 -qscale:v 5 -r 20 -b:v 9600k movie.mp4` — see the linked question for an explanation of the path. But more importantly, you need to put the encoder options *after* the `-i` part, and you should tell ffmpeg which encoder you want. `qscale` is valid for MPEG-4 Part 2, but perhaps you want H.264 instead? Use `ffmpeg -i Image%03d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 23 movie.mp4` instead then, and see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 as well as https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Comment: Oh, and *probably* not a good idea to use a six year old tutorial for ffmpeg—quite a few things have changed since then. It's not your fault, but there's still a ton of bad information out there. Good that you downloaded a newest version from the website, though. Feel free to ask a new question if you have troubles with the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to supply the full path or the program must be in the search path.

In your case you do not have your current directory (.) in the search path.
Note that this is a **good** thing.  Putting . in your search path allows unwanted things like browsing my homedir and typing 'ls'. (guess which `ls` will be executed. It is not /bin/ls).

So, supply the path oruse `./ffmpeg`  (the dot stands for the current directory. So dot slash file means 'that file in this directory'.